# GET 200 (OK) error after axios call only before refreshing page

Tags: http, vue.js, axios

I have an axios call fetching some json data.

Method is get, and i need credentials to login.

```
checkCreds2 (username, password) {
  var configJITIT = {
    withCredentials: true,
    method: 'get',
    url: 'xxx',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    params: {
      $format: 'json'
    }
  }
  this.axios(configJITIT)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.config)
    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log('success!')
    }
  })
    .catch(function (error) {...})
```

}

Thing is, when i do the call and type in my credentials, the console logs an error: GET Status 200 (OK)

The problem is, my data is not displayed as long my request gets an error.
I have to refresh the page so the data is displayed.

It really is an error.
After refreshing the page, everything's fine.

I don't want to have to refresh the page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your params object looks a bit strange. Did you try to use the `get` method from axios ? It has all the correct configuration you need, you just have to provide your additional parameters.

Example:

```
axios.get('/user', {
    params: {
      ID: 12345
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: well, im getting data from a sap system via odata - the params there look like $format or something like that. :)

Comment: yep, thats exactly how my final link looks like:)

Comment: if you remove all the code inside the `then()` and leave only `console.log('success!')`. also if you check the xhr in the network what do you see ? `200 OK` ?

Comment: first thing: doesnt change anything. how can i  check xhr?

Comment: Open `Chrome`, choose `Network` tab select `XHR` tab and refresh the page

Comment: Status in xhr tab is 200 after refreshing!

Comment: how do you call that `checkCreds2 ` method ? with a click ?

Comment: yes, with a click.
            <form class="ui form loginForm"  @submit.prevent="checkCreds2">

Comment: any more ideas? :)